# Runing Node.js socket server locally on windows

Tags: networking, command-line, localhost, node.js

I have seen the introductory course on YouTube (1 hour), and I wanted to try and "clone" the chat example on my pc.
I have installed node.js for windows (0.8.2), and I have opened the command prompt in the start menu folder called: "Node.js command prompt",
Then I created a file named: "chat.js".

chat.js:

```
var net = require('net');
var sockets = [];

var server = net.createServer(function (socket){
    sockets.push(socket);
    socket.write("Hello and Welcome!\n");
    socket.on('data', function(data){
        for(var i  = 0;i<sockets.length;i++){
            if(socket != sockets[i]){
                sockets[i].write(data);
            }
        }
    });
    socket.on('end', function(){
        sockets.splice (sockets.indexOf(socket),1);
        socket.end("Ended Chat");
    });
});

server.listen(8000);
```

When I type node chat.js I get the following:
[image]

And it stays that way.
When I try to connect via telnet I get the following:
[image]

**What should I do in order to start the server correctly and start communicating with it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The telnet command is wrong. Should be `telnet 127.0.0.1 8000`. Space instead of a `:` between hostname and port. You can see this from the error message that it's trying to connect via port `23` which is the default for the Telnet program.